# Why are my absolutely-positioned elements misplaced in some cases?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a list of posts that I'm using ng-repeat with bootstrap grid to create seperate rows for each post. Inside of these I have a font-awesome icon bookmark with absolute positioning for text on top of that icon.They all have relative positioning to the div class='image-wrapper' that they are inside. My question is the absolute positioning of the date seems to be different visually even though the css is the same.

```
<div ng-repeat="post in $ctrl.posts | filter:{category:'tournament'}">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
          <img src="{{post.photo_link}}" class='img-fluid pb-3'></img>
      </div><!--End od col-sm-6-->
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">
                  <h2 class='zaffre text-center h5' ng-bind="post.title"></h2>
              </div><!--End of col-12-->
              <div class="col-12 text-center image-wrapper">
                <i class="fa fa-bookmark fa-5x zaffre" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <div class='month-wrapper'><span ng-bind="post.date | date:'MMM'"></span></div>
                <div class='date-wrapper'><span ng-bind="post.date | date:'dd'"></span></div>
                <p class='text-sm-left mt-2' ng-bind="post.body"></p>
              </div>         
          </div><!--End of row-->

      </div><!--End od col-sm-6-->
    </div><!--End of row-->
  </div><!--End of ng-repeat-->
```

CSS

```
.image-wrapper{
position:relative;
```

}

```
.month-wrapper{
   position:absolute;
   top:4%;
   left:45%;
   color:white;
}

.date-wrapper{
   position:absolute;
   top:12%;
   left:48%;
   color:white;
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: for large text, text going under date month box. Do you want to keep text beside the date month box?

Comment: Why visually would the positioning of the dates not be in the same place if the ng-repeat is giving each row the same css? Apologize, I thought the photo with the information provided made that obvious.

Comment: Yes, @SarowerJahan. I want to keep that text wrapping but have the date and month all sit like the second bookmark not the first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your top value (12%) varies depending on the height of the box. Percentage values are unreliable for that reason. Instead, use pixel values or rework the layout to use padding or another mechanism for positioning.

Comment: I'm going to give to this one because while both answers are saying use pixels instead of percentages. I didn't really get why until this answer said the height of the box was changing based on the post.body I imagine. Although I know this is going to be off as the screen width resizes. I could make changes at break points but that still won't fix entirely. Any thoughts on a better approach?

Comment: I'm just gonna add this in case anyone else comes along with the same type question. So that I could continue to use percentages so the text would stay relatively in the same position even as I resized. I made the image-wrapper div have a specified min-height of 300px and max-height of 300.2px. This will mean I can only have a certain amount of text for my post.body but I don't forsee that being a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change the HTML structure like below:

```
       <div class="col-12 text-center image-wrapper">
            <div class='date-panel'>
                <i class="fa fa-bookmark fa-5x zaffre" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <div class='month-wrapper'><span ng-bind="post.date | date:'MMM'"></span></div>
                <div class='date-wrapper'><span ng-bind="post.date | date:'dd'"></span></div>
            </div>
            <p class='text-panel' ng-bind="post.body"></p>
        </div>
```

Change CSS like below:

```
.date-panel{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
.text-panel{
    padding-left:100px;
}
```